# Sending basic auth details with Ajax request to Tomcat9 web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors, tomcat9

I am trying to call a Java/Spring web service from another server via JQuery/Ajax

Clicking a button triggers the code:

```
var request = $.ajax({
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                method: "GET",
                url: "http://<ipOfWebService>/api/myEndPoint/4313991?country=UK",
                dataType: "xml",
                crossDomain: true,
                username: "basicUsername",
                password: "basicPassword",
            })
```

I've configured the CORS Filter as per the [Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter), specifying the domainOfAjaxCall as the allowed origin:

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>ipAddress1,http://dev.ajaxCaller.com</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
      <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
      <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers,Authorization</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
      <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.support.credentials</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>cors.preflight.maxage</param-name>
      <param-value>10</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

I am prompted for the username/password before it successfully calls the web service:

[image: Screenshot of Auth Request]

Most threads I've seen recommend replacing the username & password with a beforeSend e.g.

```
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa( "basicUsername:basicPassword"))
        },
```

Unfortunately this results in a error, despite the CORS Filter being configured:

```
Failed to load http://<ipOfWebService>/api/myEndPoint/4313991?country=UK: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '<domainOfAjaxCall>' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

I've also tried switching the beforeSend for:

```
headers: {
"Authorization": "Basic " + btoa("basicUsername:basicPassword")
```

},

With the same result.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Add OPTIONS method to your web service with CORS header and set "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" to "Authorization".

This should work!

Why?

When Auth headers are used in cross domain requests, a request to OPTIONS method will be sent first. If OPTIONS has proper headers, it will proceed to method you have in your request.

Comment: If I understand correctly then I already have that defined in the CORS Filter.  

I've added my specific CORS Filter for clarity